# Open Close principle with events

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm building a system where there is a datatable on the main form that must be updated when the user inserts or deletes something. Once there are specific forms to do these tasks, the datatable of the main form is updated when the CRUD operation is successfully terminated on the dialog form. The problem is whenever I must add other form that make some change on the data, I must create an event that has the same intention on the dialog form and assign it to the method that populates the datatable, violating the open closed principle. Here is an example:

Creating an event on the Update Product dialog form:

```
public static event Action OnUpdateProduct
```

Creating an event on the New Product dialog form:

```
public static event Action OnUpdateProduct
```

Assign to the FrmNewProduct.OnUpdateProduct event in the main form:

```
FrmNewProduct.OnUpdateProduct += FillDataTable;
```

Assign to the FrmUpdateProduct.OnUpdateProduct event in the main form:

```
FrmUpdateProduct.OnUpdateProduct += FillDataTable;
```

How do I do to fix this in order to decouple the main form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EventAggregator design pattern (http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) will help you. It works as a mediator between publisher and subscriber, essentially decoupling both.

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a global singleton EventDispatcher class with OnUpdateProduct and a TriggerUpdateProduct() companion function. In your main form you attach to the one event and you can fire it from multiple other forms.

What you need is just a decoupling between the event triggers and its subscriptions. My example is just a simple way to do it and you might consider other approaches like zmechanic's suggestion